# function being called multiple times when passed to a child React component with useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I have a page with multiple ChildComponent tags and I would like each ChildComponent to be told which API to call depending on which ChildComponent a user clicks on. The onClick() will open a modal.

What I am noticing is the API call is made twice when the Modal box opens. When i close the Modal box, the API call is made again.

I understand from this post that the behaviour from React is correct - [Function being called multiple times in React functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61394328/function-being-called-multiple-times-in-react-functional-component)

Is there another way to architect this so only one axios API call once?

```
const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

export default function ParentComponent() {
    const fetchPosts = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const result = await axios(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`);
            setPosts(result.data.data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }, []);
}
```

```
<ChildComponent
      fetchPosts={fetchPosts}
      onClick={handleOnclick}
/>
```

```
const ChildComponent = ({ fetchPosts }) => {
    useEffect(
       () => props.fetchPosts, 
       [props.fetchPosts]
    );
}

export default memo(ChildComponent);
```

Comment: where do you control open/close state for modal?

Comment: In the parent component @AndriiVynarchuk

Comment: The question does not have enough details. Please show the opening/closing of modal. Atleast show the JSX of the Parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question and your task well I will try to write my solution.

As you have modal control state at parent component and every time it changes it triggers your parent component to rerender and your child component is rerendered as well and since function is an object in JS, so your fetch function will have different links every rerender and your useEffect in ChildComponent will think that your function was changed.

So, I suppose the best solution is to add memo for your child components like `export default memo(ChildComponent)` (*you can import memo from 'react'*). And after that you should wrap fetchPosts and handleOnclick with [useCallback](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback). You will have something like that `const fetchPosts = useCallback(() => doSomething(), [])`

Hope it helps.

Comment: No axios calls are made with the suggested changes. I have update the code in the original question to check if I've done it correctly @Andrii Vynarchuk

Comment: @IlyasPatel okay I got you, but unfortunately I can't see and test your full code, so I mostly have to guess. You can leave empty array as dependencies in useEffect and it will be triggered while mounting OR you can add a new state in ChildComponent that will trigger useEffect when it changes. It depends on what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are under React 18 there is this error in the reactivity check this post https://taig.medium.com/prevent-react-from-triggering-useeffect-twice-307a475714d7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).